# How to set custom colors for Odoo 12 calendar view events?

Tags: odoo, odoo-12

There is a good tutorial on how to achieve this in Odoo-8 here:
[Tutorial](https://www.odoo.yenthevg.com/adding-custom-colors-to-agenda-and-kanban-views/) , but it doesn't work on Odoo-12.

Odoo natively allows you to set a field of your model as a basis for color differentiation in calendar view.

```
 <calendar ...  color="your_model_field">
```

The problem is that he will decide automagically what color to assign to every value.
I need to be able to **decide what color mapping to use**.

Doing some diving in the web module js files, more specifically on
*web/static/src/js/views/calendar/calendar_renderer.js*  on line 266
I found a promising function which appears to be the one responsible for deciding which color to set.

```js
    getColor: function (key) {
        if (!key) {
            return;
        }
        if (this.color_map[key]) {
            return this.color_map[key];
        }
        // check if the key is a css color
        if (typeof key === 'string' && key.match(/^((#[A-F0-9]{3})|(#[A-F0-9]{6})|((hsl|rgb)a?\(\s*(?:(\s*\d{1,3}%?\s*),?){3}(\s*,[0-9.]{1,4})?\))|)$/i)) {
            return this.color_map[key] = key;
        }
        var index = (((_.keys(this.color_map).length + 1) * 5) % 24) + 1;
        this.color_map[key] = index;
        return index;
    },
```

This function is fed the value of your field (for every calendar event) and returns the color to be used "supposedly" as background for the calendar event square.

According to the second if statement, if you manage to instantiate the CalendarRenderer class with a color_map object which has the possible values of your field as keys and color codes as values you should be ok.

According the the third if statement, if the values of your field are strings with color codes (#FFF, rgb(x, y, z) , etc) they will be set in the color_map object and returned to be used as background colors.

The last part I guess is how odoo decides on a color when no mapping is provided.

I tried both approaches with the same efect:

[Image displaying the calendar view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8PlLj.png)

Namely, all the calendar events are rendered with the default color taken from the fullcalendar.css stylesheet (line 529), but the color reference displays correctly on the sidebar to the right.

I would appreciate any light shed on this matter, It has to be possible to make this work!.

Thanks.

Comment: Hi Emilio, were you able to solve this in the end?